# Spring-restdocs: how to make parameters, paths and response fields code blocks

Tags: java, documentation, spring-restdocs

I'm using spring-restdocs to generate API docs, and I would like all parameters, paths and response field JSON paths to be printed as code sections (backticks in Asciidoc) inside the tables.

For instance, the JSON path sprockets.[].widgets.[].contentType is harder to read in a variable-width font than `sprockets.[].widgets.[].contentType`, printed in monospace.

The same goes for request parameters and path parameters - these are tokens that should be printed in monospace.

What is the simplest way to achieve this with Spring-restdocs?

Thanks in advance for any help.

G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that REST Docs should do this by default. I've opened an issue that'll be fixed in 1.1: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/230. Thanks for the suggestion.

In the meantime, you can do what you want by using [custom snippet templates](http://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/html5/#documenting-your-api-customizing-snippets). For example, to customize the formatting of the paths of the request fields, you need to provide a `request-fields.snippet` file in `src/test/resources/org/springframework/restdocs/templates` that looks like this:

```
|===
|Path|Type|Description

{{#fields}}
|`{{path}}`
|{{type}}
|{{description}}

{{/fields}}
|===
```

Note the backticks around `{{path}}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the asciidoctor formatting codes such as 'm' for monospace:

```
m|{{path}}
```

You can even change column widths and alignment, eg three columns with relative widths 4-4-2 and the third column centre aligned:

```
[cols="2*4,^2"]
|===
|Parameter|Description|Optional
```

(I know that's not what you asked but for anyo spring-restdocs users new to asciidoc maybe it helps to know that there are lots of easy options for customisation)

See http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#cols-format